# Desafio NSA - "Treze homens e um carregamento"

Tags: php, lógica

Navegando pela internet a procura de desafios (para serem resolvidos com programação), achei o "Treze homens e um carregamento", onde dito que faz parte dos desafios aleatórios da NSA ([link](https://revistagalileu.globo.com/Ciencia/noticia/2016/08/voce-consegue-resolver-estes-problemas-de-logica-da-nsa.html)).

---

## O desafio

Após sua última viagem, os **13 piratas** do navio Turing se reúnem em sua taberna favorita para discutir como **irão dividir um baú de moedas de ouro**. Depois de muito debate, o capitão Códigus diz: “Arrrrrrrgh, o carregamento precisa ser distribuído igualmente entre nós”. E assim é feito. O capitão dá as moedas, uma por uma, e cada pirata aguarda ansioso sua recompensa. Conforme o capitão se aproxima do final da pilha, porém, ele percebe que **há três moedas a mais**.

Após um silencio breve e constrangedor, um dos piratas diz: “eu mereço uma moeda extra porque eu carreguei o navio enquanto o resto de vocês dormia”. Outro afirma: “Bem, eu mereço uma moeda extra porque cozinhei toda a comida ao longo da viagem”. Logo começa uma intensa troca de chutes, socos e garrafadas pela posse do dinheiro restante. **O dono do estabelecimento, irritado com a bagunça, expulsa um pirata particularmente violento que havia quebrado uma mesa**, e ele é obrigado a devolver todas as suas moedas para o grupo. É dado o aviso: “ou vocês ficam em paz ou todos serão expulsos daqui!”.

Os piratas voltam a seus lugares e o capitão, que ficou com **apenas 12 piratas, continua a distribuir as moedas**. “Uma para você... Outra para você.” Agora, quando a pilha está próxima do fim, **ele percebe que há cinco moedas sobrando**. Começa uma nova briga. **O capitão, com medo de que sejam expulsos do local, manda o pirata mais estressado embora**. Agora, com **apenas 11 membros, a divisão dá certo**, cada um recebe a mesma quantidade de moedas e todos vão dormir em paz.

**Considerando que houvesse menos de 1000 moedas**, quantas moedas os piratas dividiram entre si? **Só há uma resposta possível para um valor abaixo de 1000**.

---

Partindo da ideia em resolver e sabendo que haveriam vários valores a serem calculados, brevemente fiz em `php` para tentar a solução (claro, sem ler o resultado, para não perder a graça), e felizmente deu certo:

```
<?php

// 11 piratas, sobra 0
$piratas_11 = array();

$max_moedas = 1000;
while($max_moedas > 0) {

    if($max_moedas%11 == 0){
    
        array_push($piratas_11, $max_moedas);
    }

    $max_moedas--;
}


// 12 piratas, sobra 5
$piratas_12 = array();

foreach($piratas_11 as $v) {
    
    if($v%12 == 5){
    
        array_push($piratas_12, $v);
    }
}


// 13 piratas, sobra 3
$piratas_13 = array();

foreach($piratas_12 as $v) {
    
    if($v%13 == 3){
    
        array_push($piratas_13, $v);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($piratas_13);
```

*Resultado:*

```
Array
(
    [0] => 341
)
```

Não tentei fazer de outras formas, então:

O que gostaria, é saber como vocês fariam, se há uma forma de solução mais curta e eficiente, usando ou não outras funções, etc.

> Acredito que sempre há uma forma de dar mais eficiência ao código, e
> nisso sempre aprendo bastante.

Comment: Haha, só um momento, vou tentar aqui também

Comment: Eu não consegui ver uma implementação melhor, pois, você pega os valores possíveis menores que 1000 de 11 piratas que restarão 0. E a partir de então você consegue descobrir o número exato testando por outros valores dos outros pitaras. Ótima ideia! Parabéns!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Você consegue fazer isso com apenas um laço de repetição. Considerando que eles possuem `N` moedas, quando é dividido entre 13 piratas, sobram 3 moedas, o que significa que `N-3` é múltiplo de 13 e, portanto, `N-3 % 13 = 0`; quando dividido por 12 piratas, sobram 5 moedas, portanto `N-5` é múltiplo de 12, o que implica em `N-5 % 12 = 0`; por fim, quando dividido em 11 piratas, não sobram moedas, e, portanto, `N` é múltiplo de 11, `N % 11 = 0`. O valor de `N` será aquele que satisfaz as três condições e é menor que 1000.

```
foreach(range(0, 1000, 11) as $i) {
    if (($i - 3) % 13 == 0 and ($i - 5) % 12 == 0 and ($i % 11) == 0) {
        echo $i, PHP_EOL;
        break;
    }
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/EthicalGlisteningLight) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/1Z8oVs)</sup>

Perceba que, sabendo que o resultado será, necessariamente, múltiplo de 11, não precisamos percorrer todos os valores de 0 a 1000, mas apenas os múltiplos de 11, por isso o terceiro parâmetro de `range` foi definido como tal.

Comment: Bem pensado.. +1

Comment: Muito bom, na hora nem me passou usar o and. Fiz update na pergunta.

Comment: +1 pela sacada de usar um step de 11.

Comment: Talvez seja micro-otimização, mas se o range já usa um step de 11, não precisa testar `$i % 11` (sempre será zero). E como sabemos que com 12 e 13 piratas sobraram moedas, então dá para assumir que há mais que 11 moedas (senão teria faltado e não sobrado), e por isso o range poderia começar em 22 :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo exato, lembro que na época eu cheguei a cogitar isso, mas optei em deixar o código mais de acordo com o texto possível para simplificar o entendimento.

Answer (score 7):

Por enquanto a minha versão melhorada com base no geral, com foco no mínimo de variáveis e funções:

```
for ($c = 1000; $c > 0; $c--)
    if (($c%11 == 0) && ($c%12 == 5) && ($c%13 == 3))
        echo $c;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$max = 1000;

while ($max > 0) {

    if($max%11 == 0 && ($max-5)%12 == 0 && ($max-3)%13 == 0){
        echo $max;
    }

    $max--;
}
```